# OpenEJB: How to exclude jar from module search?

Tags: openejb

I use OpenEJB to run unit tests for applications ultimately deployed to WebSphere Application Server. My problem is a(n unavoidable) dependency on the WAS runtime jar.  I've added an expression to the exclude property (I've also tried the physical path):

```
    p.put("openejb.deployments.classpath.exclude", ".*?runtime-6.1.*?");
    // p.put("openejb.deployments.classpath.exclude", "C:/Users/user/.m3/repository/was/runtime/6.1/runtime-6.1.jar");
    p.put("openejb.exclude-include.order", "include-exclude");
```

This value is confirmed in the logs:

```
OpenEJB.options-2014-08-07-main--INFO -OpenEJB.options:Using 'openejb.exclude-include.order=include-exclude'
OpenEJB.options-2014-08-07-main--INFO -OpenEJB.options:Using 'openejb.deployments.classpath.include=.*eed-jar.*'
OpenEJB.options-2014-08-07-main--INFO -OpenEJB.options:Using 'openejb.deployments.classpath.exclude=.*?runtime-6.1.*?'
```

but the jar is still being inspected for loadable modules:

```
OpenEJB.startup.config-2014-08-07-main--INFO -OpenEJB.startup.config:Found EjbModule in classpath: C:\Users\user\.m3\repository\was\runtime\6.1\runtime-6.1.jar
```

The result is startup failure for OpenEJB:

```
org.apache.openejb.OpenEjbContainer$InvalidApplicationException: org.apache.openejb.config.ValidationFailedException: Module failed validation. AppModule(name=)
```

and

```
WARNING: can't load com.ibm.ws.management.j2ee.ManagementBean
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: Management
```

I've been creating a 0-length dummy file and renaming `runtime-6.1.jar` to execute the tests in Eclipse, but I need to restore the jar to run the Maven build (which Eclipse will then bind to, necessitating a restart to rename the jar).

What's the right way to exclude this jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to set `openejb.deployments.classpath.filter.descriptors` to true as well. See http://tomee.apache.org/application-discovery-via-the-classpath.html

Otherwise, filters will not be applied to resources that contain a descriptor file (ejb-jar.xml).

If you still have problems, you can debug through `org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentsResolves` and see why your resources aren't excluded.